# Latlng to UTM conversion with forced zone

Tags: qgis, geotools

I'm trying to convert a set of latlng coords to UTM but the points in the set are across two different UTM zones, 32T and 33T.

This causes two near points like

44.51601173544275, 11.992860160820502
44.51601173544275, 12.012860160820502

to be converted to

32T 737655.84708598 4933706.271726263
33T 262397.6792462121 4933704.362693829

Code is:

```
LatLng latlng = new LatLng(44.51601173544275, 12.012860160820502);
latlng.toWGS84();
UTMRef utm = latlng.toUTMRef();
System.out.println(utm);
// Prints 33T 262397.6792462121 4933704.362693829
```

For some reason, when qGIS reads those points seems to ignore the zone and just read the numerical coords, so the final result is that the points are very distant from each other:

[image: qgis result]

Black lines are 32T and 33T.

So, the question is: is this a qGIS bug or a conversion issue? Can I force the conversion to use a specific zone (32T) as a workaround? Right now I'm using Jcoords for conversion but in my project I already have Geotools loaded.

Thanks, regards
Maurizio

Comment: How did you do the conversion? Normally you have to specify which zone you want to reproject to, and all points go into that.

Comment: With Jcoords:

LatLng latlng = new LatLng(44.51601173544275, 12.012860160820502);
latlng.toWGS84();
UTMRef utm = latlng.toUTMRef();
System.out.println(utm);
// prints 33T 262397.6792462121 4933704.362693829

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Jcoords issue, but not necessarily a bug.

QGIS can read coordinates, but not the UTM zone given in front of it as Jcoords does.

Usually, we load WGS84 data into QGIS with EPSG:4326, and transform it into the coordinates of the desired UTM zone. These have EPSG-codes in the range of 32600 + UTM zone.

So if you read the data programmatically, you have to split them by UTM zone, and give every so created layer the appropriate EPSG code.

If most of your data lies within one UTM zone, you can transform all data with QGIS (or GDAL) into that zone. This will keep your data together.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Andre, I'm accepting your answer as it seems the "correct" one. Anyway I've solved patching Jcoord this way:

```
--- LatLng.java.orig    2006-02-11 14:48:58.000000000 +0100
+++ LatLng.java 2014-02-13 19:11:49.307716000 +0100
@@ -121,13 +121,17 @@
   }


+  public UTMRef toUTMRef() {
+     return toUTMRef(null);
+  }
+  
   /**
    * Convert this latitude and longitude to a UTM reference.
    * 
    * @return the converted UTM reference
    * @since 1.0
    */
-  public UTMRef toUTMRef() {
+  public UTMRef toUTMRef(Integer forcedLongitudeZone) {
     double UTM_F0 = 0.9996;
     double a = RefEll.WGS84.getMaj();
     double eSquared = RefEll.WGS84.getEcc();
@@ -157,6 +161,8 @@
       }
     }

+    if (forcedLongitudeZone != null) longitudeZone = forcedLongitudeZone;
+
     double longitudeOrigin = (longitudeZone - 1) * 6 - 180 + 3;
     double longitudeOriginRad = longitudeOrigin * (Math.PI / 180.0);
```

Overloading the toUTMRef() with an int param allows to force the zone, so note the difference:

```
utm = latlng.toUTMRef();
System.out.println(utm); // 33T 262592.1445972342 4933528.658057731
utm = latlng.toUTMRef(32);
System.out.println(utm); // 32T 739452.0537175534 4933603.769506776
```

Regards,
Maurizio